# How to globally define variables from c++ class, with section attribute

Tags: c++

I am trying to write some code to make the canbus peripherals for a SAME51 work properly. The canbus peripheral needs access to system ram to work, and this RAM must be in the first 64K for it to work properly.

I have figured out how to globally declare a variable using the section attribute, then I have modified the linker script to be sure that this array is at the desired location, first in RAM. This all works like it should, I can verify with the .map file.

The problem is this MCU has two canbus peripherals and I would like to use them both simultaneously. To do that I'd like to define the ram array from within the class, but I get errors saying the section attribute is only valid for global variables. I think doing it this way will make the code for canbus more universal, I won't have to add checks to make sure the proper global defined ram array is being used.

If I give the array the static attribute from within the class the code will compile, but when it comes time to link everything together the code fails and says it can't find the reference to the class variable.

Is there a better way around this?

Thank you!

```
sam_can.h
    class SAM_CAN
    {
    public:
    private:
    static uint32_t can_msg_ram[MSG_RAM_SIZE] __attribute__((section(".canram")));
    };

cam_can.cpp
    enum can_status SAM_CAN::begin()
    {
    struct can_config can_cfg = {
        id :
        _canid,                     // Peripheral ID
        regs :  
        #ifndef ID_CAN1 
        CAN0,                       // Offset to registers
        #else   
        ((_canid == ID_CAN0) ? CAN0 : CAN1),    // Offset to registers, switch between CAN0 and CAN1
        #endif
        msg_ram :
        can_msg_ram,               // Pointer to start of Canram
        ....
    };
```

undefined reference to `SAM_CAN::can_msg_ram'

Comment: Instance of `class` is a 'whole' object, so you could not simply place one part of a class instance in one section of memory and another part in totally different section of memory. There are 2 options, I see, basically. First you instantiate a whole CAN object in `section(".canram")`. Or second option is to allocate `can_msg_ram[MSG_RAM_SIZE]` in `section(".canram")`, instantiate CAN object in 'normal' memory and pass a pointer to `can_msg_ram` array to CAN object in constructor. I'd go with second option.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I can globally define the set of can_msg_ram and make sure that I am accessing the proper one in the functions, only slightly more work!

Thank you!